# Jet colormap to grayscale

Tags: matlab, colors, rgb, grayscale

I have a jet colormap:

[image: jet colormap]

and I would like to know if there's some way to convert to a grayscale. I can't use average because maximum and minimum value goes to the same gray color. Or if there's some way to convert to another color palette.

I can't find on Google a function to convert it. MATLAB uses some thing called `rgb2ind` but I would like to know the formula.

Comment: Jet is unanimously regarded as one of the worst colormaps available, despite its popularity...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First let me create an indexed image using the Jet colormap:

```
img = repmat(uint8(0:255), 100, 1);
cmap = jet(256);

imshow(img, 'Colormap',cmap)
```

[image: jet]

The straightforward conversion using IND2GRAY produces the following:

```
J = ind2gray(img,cmap);
imshow(J)
```

[image: jet_to_gray]

As you expressed, the min/max converge to the same value. From what I understood, you are looking to map the jet colormap to linearly go from dark to light shades of gray. For this, we can [reorder using the hue value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245842/sorting-colors-in-matlab/2246189#2246189) which we get with the RGB2HSV function. Compare the following against the original colormap:

```
[~,idx] = sortrows(rgb2hsv(cmap), -1);  %# sort by Hue
C = gray(256);
C = C(idx,:);

imshow(img, 'Colormap',C)
```

[image: hue_sorted]

Answer (score 4):

create the image in MATLAB

```
image(1:64);axis off;colormap(jet);
```

save the image as tiff, crop out the borders with Paintbrush and save as '\directorypath\jetmage.tiff'.

load the image in MATLAB

```
jetmage=imread('\\directorypath\jetmage.tiff');
```

get image size

```
[szX,szY,szZ]=size(jetmage);
```

get a row of image for each color, red, green and blue.

```
r=reshape(jetmage(uint8(szX/2),:,1),[szY,1]);
g=reshape(jetmage(uint8(szX/2),:,2),[szY,1]);
b=reshape(jetmage(uint8(szX/2),:,3),[szY,1]);
```

plot the intensity profile for each color for that row.

```
plot(r,'r-');hold on;
plot(g,'g-');hold on;
plot(b,'b-');hold on;
```

The plot should be something like so:

[image]

you can use array `[r,g,b]` as the look-up-table or base on that
figure out a way to get the 'formula' from array `[r,g,b]`

Answer (score 1):

`rgb2ind` converts the RGB values for each pixel into indices within a color map. If you use the 2 input version with a color map input, then it will look-up the closest color in the color map that matches each pixel. This will basically give you a single number for each pixel, rather than an RGB value.

For example, if you load your image

```
RGB = imread(imagefilename);
```

then, since the Jet color map is returned by `jet`, then you can get the indexed data using

```
mapsize = 256;
map = jet(mapsize);
ind = rgb2ind(RGB, map);
```

You can then display the image using any color map

```
colormap(map)
image(ind)
colormap('gray')
```

Don't use imagesc because it may stretch the dynamic range of your image unacceptably.

Answer (score 0):

Python implementation of the answer given by teng (assuming a default matplotlib jetmap).

```
import pylab as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def PIL2array(img):
    return numpy.array(img.getdata(),
                numpy.uint8).reshape(img.size[1], img.size[0], 3)
def array2PIL(arr, size):
    mode = 'RGBA'
    arr = arr.reshape(arr.shape[0]*arr.shape[1], arr.shape[2])
    if len(arr[0]) == 3:
       arr = numpy.c_[arr, 255*numpy.ones((len(arr),1), numpy.uint8)]
    return Image.frombuffer(mode, size, arr.tostring(), 'raw', mode, 0, 1)

def return_x(y,color,direction):

    if color == "blue" and direction == "up":
       m = (4.0 + 6.0/11.0)
       c = 0.5
    elif color == "blue" and direction == "down":
       m = -3.226
       c = 2.097
    elif color == "green" and direction == "up":
       m = 4.0
       c = -0.5
    elif color == "green" and direction == "down":
       m = -3.704
       c = 3.370
    elif color == "red" and direction == "up":
       m = 3.223
       c = -1.129
    elif color == "red" and direction == "down":
       m = -4.545
       c = 5.041
    else:
       print "Returning y:: INCORRECT OPTIONS"
       m = 1
       c = 0

    return (y-c)/m 

# x >= y
def big_equal(x,y):
    return x > y or np.allclose(x,y)

# x <= y
def less_equal(x,y):
    return x < y or np.allclose(x,y)

def convert_jet_to_grey(img_array,n):
    new_image = np.zeros((img_array.shape[0],img_array.shape[1]))
    for i in range(img_array.shape[0]):
        for j in range(img_array.shape[1]):
            pixel_blue = img_array[i,j,2]
            pixel_green = img_array[i,j,1]
            pixel_red = img_array[i,j,0]
            if (pixel_blue < 1) and big_equal(pixel_blue,0.5) and less_equal(pixel_green,0.5) :
               #print "a1"
               #print "i,j = ",i,",",j
               new_image[i,j] = return_x(pixel_blue,"blue","up")**n
            elif np.allclose(pixel_blue,1.0) and big_equal(pixel_green,0):
                 #print "b1"
                 #print "i,j = ",i,",",j
                 new_image[i,j] = return_x(pixel_green,"green","up")**n
            elif (pixel_blue < 1) and big_equal(pixel_blue,0.4) and big_equal(pixel_green,0.5):
                 #print "c1"
                 #print "i,j = ",i,",",j
                 new_image[i,j] = return_x(pixel_green,"blue","down")**n
            elif (pixel_red < 1) and big_equal(pixel_red,0.4) and big_equal(pixel_green,0.5):
                 #print "c2"
                 #print "i,j = ",i,",",j
                 new_image[i,j] = return_x(pixel_green,"red","up")**n
            elif np.allclose(pixel_red,1.0) and big_equal(pixel_green,0):
                 #print "b2"
                 #print "i,j = ",i,",",j
                 new_image[i,j] = return_x(pixel_green,"green","down")**n
            elif (pixel_red < 1) and big_equal(pixel_red,0.5) and less_equal(pixel_green,0.5):
           #print "a2"
           #print "i,j = ",i,",",j
           new_image[i,j] = return_x(pixel_blue,"red","down")**n
        else:
           print "Leaving 0:: NOT A JET IMAGE"

return new_image

def main():


   img = Image.open('test.jpg')
   arr = PIL2array(img)

   img_new = convert_jet_to_grey(arr/255.0,1)
   imgplot = plt.imshow(img_new)
   plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```