# How to make a matplotlib to plot a 3D tricontour?

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

How I can make a chart type COMSOL with matplotlib using 3D ( like tricontourf in 2D ) with different planes?

[image: Example Chart]

[example chart COMSOL](http://i.ytimg.com/vi/PmyXon1NpAg/maxresdefault.jpg)

Comment: So you want to make the two planes intersect in 3D? Unless you post your code (as minimal as possible) no one will be able and willing to help you here

Comment: I found now this [Python plot - stacked image slices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15582105/python-plot-stacked-image-slices). this is what you like to make but using tricontourf

Comment: Stop adding links in comments and deleting them later. Post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for adding links in comments and deleting them later this is my first question...

This is the code that I using to plot 2d. I have a matrix with 4 columns:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1); fig.set_figwidth(17); fig.set_figheight(7);

    x = a[:, 0]; 
    y = a[:, 1]; 
    t = a[:, 3];

    fig_1 = ax.tricontourf(x, y, t); 
    ax.tricontour(x, y, t, colors = 'k'); ax.scatter(x, y)
    ax.set_xlabel("Eje y [mm]", fontsize = 20); ax.set_ylabel("Eje x [mm]", fontsize = 

plt.show()
```

but when I try to make plans in 3d it does not work, the color layers are separated:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

cset = ax.tricontourf(x, y, t, zdir= 'z', cmap=cm.coolwarm)
fig.colorbar(cset)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Simply set offset to some z value.

```
cset = ax.tricontourf(x, y,t,  zdir= 'z', cmap=cm.coolwarm,offset=1.0)
```